# Filter exception in Kendo Ui Grid with React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I'm facing a problem with filtering in Kendo UI Grid in React. I'm getting following exception `op() is not a function`. These are not too much information but I got also a screenshot from the filter object.

The is the object where the application is returning an exception:

[image]

I tried the same example which is on the Kedno UI Grid for React website (https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/advanced-examples/stateful-grid/), and there it is working fine, but the filter object looks like this:

[image]

I don't know what is the cause of the problem or if this is actually the problem (wrong object structure as in the first image). That's why, any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Could you please provide runable example where the issue is reproduced? The first filter object ineed is incorrect and it's interesting how you get to this state - it might be cased by incorrect behavior of the filter row. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have custom filter cell with a DropDownList. The DropDownList returns the whole item on it's onChange event after version 2.0.0, and it returned only the value field in 1.0.x versions. 
This was listed as a breaking change, and in case you have custom filters with a DropDownList you need to slightly modify them to return the correct value.

Comment: @VladimirIliev, the problem is that, this behavior is only reporoducable in my application :). I cannot reproduce it in any other example and no idea why is this happenning. Is there any way manipulate the filter object? maybe it is getting there manipulated

Comment: @Xizario, i have other grids without a custom filter cell with a DropDownList and there i have the same problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue could occur if an older version of the Grid package is used with a newer version of the DropDowns as there was a change in the DropDown regarding the value format. Try updating the Grid and the DropDowns package to the latest version.